# Huge increase in CPU usage in OpenGL ES on Android after 10s

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es

I have a pretty simply OpenGL ES application running on Android - it just loads a texture atlas, then draws a load of tiles in predetermined positions

It's based on this tutorial: http://androidblog.reindustries.com/a-real-open-gl-es-2-0-2d-tutorial-part-1/

After about 10 seconds of rendering, the CPU increases rather drastically (as shown in the image), and the time taken to render each frame increase from about 1ms to about 14ms (running on my Nexus 5)

[image: CPU Usage Graph]

I timed everything in the `onDrawFrame` method, and it is entirely the fault of `GLES20.glDrawElements`

The entirety of my rendering method is this:

```
GLES20.glUseProgram(ShaderTools.sp_Image);

GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(ShaderTools.sp_Image, "vPosition");
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(ShaderTools.sp_Image, "a_texCoord");
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, uvBuffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);

int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(ShaderTools.sp_Image, "uMVPMatrix");
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, mtrxProjectionAndView, 0);

int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(ShaderTools.sp_Image, "s_texture");

GLES20.glUniform1i(mSamplerLoc, 0);

GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);
```

If anyone could shed any light onto what might be causing this, and how to rectify it, then I'd be very grateful :-)

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't look like something you're doing, or at least not in the code here. My first thought was a memory leak, or at least memory usage that causes frequent garbage collection. It's very unlikely that this is related to your problem, but you really should not have all those `glGet*` calls in your draw method. Call them once during init, and store the locations in member variables.

Comment: One more thing: If you have a different device you can try it on, that would be a good experiment. It gives you data suggesting if the problem is in your code, or more likely in the device software.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the `glGet*` calls.
 

Seems you're correct about it being an issue in the device software - I tested on my old phone (HTC Sensation XE, so about 3/4yrs old, running Android 4.4 as opposed to my Nexus' 5.1), and the CPU never went above 5%

Comment: After further testing, it appears to be related to the number passed into the `count` parameter of `glDrawElements` (`indices.length` is used in the code above) - any number greater than 16382 causes this issue. Not sure if that's any help, but that's what I found

Comment: That's good research. At least from what you show here, it's likely to be a problem in the OpenGL driver. You could try to file a bug.

Comment: What are you using to measure CPU usage on Android? What is this tool?

Comment: Android Studio lets you view CPU and RAM usage whilst you're debugging an app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nexus5 is based on a Qualcomm chipset and has an Adreno 330 GPU.

Qualcomm chipsets are known to throttle the GPU frequency  quickly if your app is rather graphics intensive / has no fps limiter / renders in (huge) native resolution (so not using the [hardware scaler](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html)).

So what probably happens is that the GPU frequency gets throttled and then you see a high cpu usage which represents the "CPU waiting for GPU" at the end of frame.

It is also possible that CPU gets throttled but in my experience this tends to happen on Samsung phones because of [DVFS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2674928), not much on Nexus ...

The good news is that a tool actually exist to monitor current CPUs & GPU frequency on Qualcomm devices, it is called [Trepn Profiler](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/trepn-power-profiler) and you can use it on non rooted devices.

So you should install this tool, configure it to display GPU frequency and CPU0 frequency as overlay, then launch your app and you'll be able to see in realtime how the GPU and/or CPU get throttled with time.

An extra note: throttling will occur more quickly when the phone is charging.

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation is that mobile devices throttle their CPU power in order to save battery.
The device might find you are using very little CPU so it's decreasing your CPU power in order to save battery.
I don't recall ever witnessing this phenomena myself, but I know it exist, not sure if it's the case here.

Edit: Perhaps you can measure if your battery usage negatively correlates to your CPU usage in this case.

Comment: The problem with measuring the battery is that the device is plugged in to allow the debugging of the CPU, and the battery is therefore recharging... xD

Comment: I didn't mean that you look at the battery icon on your phone.
On xCode you have instruments to check battery usage. Hopefully Android has the equivalent. The battery icon on your phone is obviously not accurate enough even if your phone was not recharging.
Instead of battery it might be called energy consumption or something like that.